# Hosting a WCF service behind a proxy, firewall

Tags: wcf, http, proxy, firewall

We have created a WCF using net.tcp with an anticipation that the service can work in a firewall that would accept only HTTP port. The client behind firewall can also access it.

Do we need to host the service on a static, public IP so that any client from any network can conect to it?

Ideally, we would like to host the service on a node behind a firewall (say on 192.168.0.199) so that a client on some other network could connect to it.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Well, either you need to make the service publicly visible somehow - using a public IP, or by routing a publicly visible IP on your corporate firewall to your internal server. But yes - it needs to be publicly visible one way or another.

The other option would be to connect it to the [Windows Azure Service Bus](http://www.microsoft.com/azure/servicebus.mspx) - in that case, you could keep it behind the firewall, and just establish a publicly visible IP "in the cloud" that will then route the traffic to your web server.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

I may be off on this but WCF client should have no issues communicating with a WCF server behind a firewall. Even application - level firewalls are OK in this scenario, as long as you configure them to not inspect past layer 4. Do not authenticate or do anything with your traffic at the firewall - simply NAT it to an inside IP address and you should be ok.

Couple of notes: transport security might be a little better to this observer but both transport and message level security in WCF should work without problems through firewalls. If you need message streaming though, then you are stuck with transport level security.

If your firewall (or one of your firewalls) happens to be Microsoft ISA or TMG type device, you may find this helpful: http://www.run-corp.com/how-to-configure-wcf-application-on-microsoft-isa-tmg-firewall/.